# Mobx - React: Inject and Observe together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Recently I started using mobx with react and mobx-react library.

I want to use functional React components to create my views.

I'd like to create a helper function, that takes selector function and Component, calls inject (with selector function as parameter) and observe on that Component - effectively connecting this component to mobx-react store (taken from Provider context) and providing only needed properties for this Component.

But I can't get it to work. Action is being dispatched, but views doesn't react to this change (store attributes does change, but Component doesn't react to this change).

Here's my helper function:

```
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

export function connect(selectorFunction, component) {
  return inject(selectorFunction)(observer(component));
}
```

here's my Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'utils';

const selector = (stores) => {
  return {
    counter: stores.counterStore.counter,
    double: stores.counterStore.double,
    increment: stores.counterStore.increment
  };
};

const Counter = ({ counter, double, increment }) => {
  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <p>{ counter }</p>
      <p className="double">{ double }</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>+1</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(selector, Counter);
```

and here's my store:

```
import { observable, computed, action } from 'mobx';

export default class Counter {
  @observable counter = 0;

  @action
  increment = () => {
    this.counter++;
  }

  @computed
  get double() {
    return this.counter * 2;
  }
}
```

(Not showing Provider and other simple stuff, but it is set up properly).

Thanks! Every answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at Mobx's [documentation](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#strongly-typing-inject), it looks like your selector is doing things a bit wrong. It should return an **object with stores**, and **not an object with values from stores**. Try returning the actual `counterStore` instead:

```
const selector = (stores) => {
  return {
    counterStore: stores.counterStore
  };
};
```

And use it like this in your component:

```
const Counter = ({ counterStore: { counter, double, increment } }) => {
  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <p>{ counter }</p>
      <p className="double">{ double }</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>+1</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This might have solved some other issue I didn't even know of, but my former issue still persists :)

Comment: Hm, that's weird. I used your code (locally on my computer) and noticed the issue you described. After updating it to this, it worked properly for me. Hope you find a solution!

Comment: The reason behind the current behavior is that only the `render` method of the `observer` component is being tracked, not the inject function itself. That might actually be interesting... For fun, you could try whether this solves your original problem:

`return observer(inject(selectorFunction)(observer(component)))`

see also: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/111